# Can someone help me interpret what these lines mean in MIPS?

Tags: mips32, spim

.data 0x10000000
.align 2
Array: .word 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24
Size: .word 8
Result: .word 0

So what does ".data" mean exactly and does "Size" correspond to the size of "Array" or is it simply another variable?

Also, what does "Result" mean? Is it an array of one character, which is 0?

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=mips+assembly

Answer (score 0):

`.data` is a header that is required before allocating memory for your program and specifying memory formatting. The header `.text` is required before program functions are written. The label `main:` must be placed somewhere under `.text` to indicate the starting location of the program.

`Array:`, `Size:`, and `Result:` are user defined labels and haven't allocated memory.

For that use `.space "# of bytes"`, not `.word`.